# How to onFocus on v-text-field and change value to empty

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to set the value to empty on a `v-text-field` when `onFocus`.

I have tried the `onFocus` attribute but nothing happen. I want to clear the value on focus and not using the clearable button from vuetify.

```
<v-text-field type="number" value="0"></v-text-field>
```

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@focus` event to trigger a method.
Here is an example with an input.
I used [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text)

more info on Vue.js [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'test'
  },
  methods: {
    onFocus() {
      this.value = '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="value" @focus="onFocus" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
<v-text-field type="number" value="0" @focus="someMethod()"></v-text-field>
```

If you check the vuetify docs

[v-text-field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields)

you will see that there is a tab **events** on the right page margin, along with **slots** and **props**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it!

I'm using `Vue2.x` (not 2.7), `Vuetify 2.x`

`<v-text-field @blur @focus />`

[https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-input/#events，](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-input/#events%EF%BC%8C) As described in the documentation, the **blur** and focus events of the `v-text-field` component are not thrown.

---

My solution:

1. Give him a ref attribute. `<v-text-field ref="textField" />`
2. define event handler

```js
methods: {
       onFocus() {
           this.$emit('focus');
       },

       onBlur() {
           this.$emit('blur');
       }
   }
```

3. use event listener

```js
mounted() {
        const input = this.$refs.textField.$el.querySelector('input');
        input.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus);
        input.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur);
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        const input = this.$refs.textField.$el.querySelector('input');
        input.removeEventListener('focus', this.onFocus);
        input.removeEventListener('blur', this.onBlur);
    }
```